# Trying to get form values in Typescript React but HTML tag is returned

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to get the form value to my useRef hook but what gets returned is the form HTML tage

I tried inferring the `HTMLFormElement` type inside the chevrons and null as the current value of my useRef hook.

Here is the rest of the the file: `NameTodo.tsx`

```
import React, { FC, ChangeEvent, FormEvent, useState, useRef } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { addTodoName, toggleNaming } from '../todoReducer';
import { RootState } from '../todoStore';

const NameTodo: FC = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const selector = useSelector((state: RootState) => { return state.todo })

    const [input, setInput] = useState<any>('');
    // Current value returns the HTML form tag itself instead of its value
    const ref = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);

    const exitNamingMenu = (): void => {
        dispatch(toggleNaming(false));
    }

    const handleInput = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setInput(event.target.value);
    }

    const submitTodoName = (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): void => {
        event.preventDefault();
        //dispatch(addTodoName(input));
        console.log(ref.current);
        dispatch(toggleNaming(false));
    }

    return (
        <div className='position-absolute start-50 mt-4 translate-middle bg-success' style={{ width: '18vw', height: '20vh' }}>
            <span className='position-absolute end-0'>
                <button className='text-white bg-success bg-opacity-10 border border-0' onClick={exitNamingMenu}>x</button>
            </span>
            <form className='d-flex flex-column' ref={ref} onSubmit={submitTodoName}>
                <p className='text-white text-center' style={{ marginTop: '3vh' }}>Enter the name of your todo-list</p>
                <input type='text' name="input" className='p-1 rounded bg-light border-0 ms-4' style={{ width: '15vw' }} onChange={handleInput}></input>
                <button type="submit" className='btn btn-light mt-3' style={{ width: "6vw", marginLeft: '6vw' }}>Enter</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default NameTodo
```

There are no errors showing up so aside from this, everything else is fine...

Thank you in advance for the responses :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ref on input elements to get the value, form doesn't have value. For complex forms, you can use libraries such as [Formik](https://formik.org/) and [React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com/).
Both of them are great.

you can check the example in the link below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-template-forked-loq0yn?file=/src/index.js

And if you want to handle it with the state:

```
function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log('Value ', inputValue);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={inputValue}
          onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      Value: {inputValue}
    </div>
  );
}
```